# How many Firestore collections and documents can I write to from 1 cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

So I have a Webhook that delivers a JSON payload to my cloud function URL.

Within that cloud function, what are my limitations for writing the JSON to my Cloud Firestore?

I can't dump my JSON payload all to one document within a collection, so I need to parse it all out to different fields.

So my cloud function will look something like:

```
await admin.firestore().collection("collection1").doc(doc1).set({
field1: data.fieldFromJson1
})
```

```
await admin.firestore().collection("collection1").doc(doc1).collection("sub-collection1").doc(doc2).set({
field2: data.fieldFromJson2
})
```

Can I do this in 1 cloud function or do I need 2 function?

I have a 100 JSON lines to parse out all over my cloud firestore, so this example is very simplified.

References & Documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there isn't any limit and as long as you stay in rate limits defined in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions) you should be fine. If it's a single webhook that has all the data then you can write all documents in a single go. You can either use `Promise.all()` or [`Batch Writes`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) (if writing a max of 500 documents).

```js
// parse data and map an array as shown below 
const promises = [
  admin.firestore().collection("collection1").doc(doc1).set({
    field1: data.fieldFromJson1
  }),
  admin.firestore().collection("collection1").doc(doc1).collection("sub-collection1").doc(doc2).set({
    field2: data.fieldFromJson2
  })
]

await Promise.all(promises)
// any other processing

res.status(200).end() // terminate the function
```

If you expect a large amount of data which can take some time to parse then make sure you set higher timeout for the function (defaults to 60 seconds).